# Using EF to query against a compile-time-unknown property

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Is there a way in EntityFramework (and the resulting LINQ) to query against a property of an entity that is not hard-coded?

Let's say, something that can be used for a search function.

```
public IList<Entity> Search (string propertyName, object value) {

    // something that'll do the following
    return context.Set<Entity>()
        .Where(x => x.propertyName == value)
        .ToList()
        ;
}
```

Comment: What did you end up doing for this?  I find myself in need of the same thing.  For a multi-field search.  I'm following this example I'm using EF instead of DataTables like their example.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandcombo/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid

Answer (score 0):

How about [Property Descriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

The following code seems to do what you require:

```
string propertyName = "Length";
List<string> testList = new List<string>();

testList.Add("String1");
testList.Add("String10");
testList.Add("String100");
testList.Add("String1000");

System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection props = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(string));

System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor desc = props.Find(propertyName, false);

IEnumerable<object> obj = from env in testList
             select desc.GetValue(env);

foreach (object it in obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(it.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Could be an elegant solution in linq-to-objects. However, Entity Framework queries will never translate to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can build equals expression manually like this

```
private static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildEqualExpression<TEntity>(string propertyName, object value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
    var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal,
        Expression.Property(param, propertyName), Expression.Constant(value));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { param });
}
```

and then use it in your LINQ query

```
var expression = BuildEqualExpression<TEntity>(propertyName, value);
return context.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression).ToList();
```